# How to post specific value with input type hidden

Tags: javascript, html, express, ejs

I have product number but first 3 digit specific, I want to enter user only last digit, I get first 3 digi from ejs <%= operatorDetails.operatorSerialNumber %> so how can I add new input value end of the specifc number and post this value.

I'm trying like this but I get error. productNoLastDigit get lastDgit and I want to post all number with productNo but `value =` part is not working.

```
<input type="text" name="productNoLastDigit" class="form-control" id="lastDigit">                                                       
<input type="hidden" name="productNo" value="<%= operatorDetails.operatorSerialNumber %> +  <script>document.write(document.getElementById('lastDigit').value)</script> " />
```

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 2):

It is not recommended to wirte JS code within input tages. You need js function so whenever productNoLastDigit is changed then append this with your previous digits and assign this new value to productNo.

```
    <input type="text" name="productNoLastDigit" class="form-control" id="lastDigit" onChange="productNoLastDigitChange()"> 
<input type="hidden" name="productNo" value="<%= operatorDetails.operatorSerialNumber %>"/>



      function productNoLastDigitChange() {
        alert("ho")
    let val = document.getElementsByName("productNoLastDigit")[0].value;
    let val2 = document.getElementsByName("productNo")[0].value;
    val2 = val2.slice(0, 3) + val
    document.getElementsByName("productNo")[0].value = val2
}
```

Comment: But how can I send data with post method ? in the post method productNo listening how can I associate with productNoLastDigitChange with my productNo output ?

Comment: your productNo  will always have concat value. So your post method will get the value that you are passing from function.

Comment: Thank you for your comment but productNoLastDigitChange function not working I dont know why ? I added in script tags

Comment: What error is it triggering. You can check console.

Comment: I added console.log("Test") in this function I couldnt see this log. So productNo return only operatorDetails.operatorSerialNumber value because function not calling

Comment: <html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" name="productNoLastDigit" class="form-control" id="lastDigit" onChange="productNoLastDigitChange()"> 
<input type="text" name="productNo" value="123"/>
<script>
    function productNoLastDigitChange() {
        alert("ho")
    let val = document.getElementsByName("productNoLastDigit")[0].value;
    let val2 = document.getElementsByName("productNo")[0].value;
    val2 = val2.slice(0, 3) + val
    document.getElementsByName("productNo")[0].value = val2
}
</script>
    </body>
</html>

Comment: It works now thank you when I change with this getElementsByName it works now.

Answer (score 1):

You can listen for `change` event on the `#lastDigit` input element and set the hidden input field value by slicing the first 3 digits and concatenating them with the changed value.

```
document.querySelector('#lastDigit').addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    let target_el = document.querySelector('input[name="productNo"]');
    let target_input_value = target_el.value;
    target_el = target_input_value.slice(0,3) + e.target.value;
});
```